# GCM and doze Doze Mode wake up time

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-doze-and-standby

I plan to GCM high priority messages to wake up my device from doze mode. How much CPU uptime do I have until device goes into doze again?

Comment: Ask a code related specific question